# Tibco AMX BPM Openspace not showing all the Items in the Workietms List

Tags: tibco, business-process-management

The issue occurs both in Workspace as well as Openspace.
As we work more on Openspace I will try to explain from Openspace perspective.
When we used to open Work List view in the Openspace in BPM 4.2,with the roles we have,it used to show around 1700-1800 Work Items.
But after migrating to BPM 4.3,for various Users its showing a different value(around 700-1300)in the Work List View.
The difference in the case do exists in the system but not coming up in the Work List View.

As a workaround when I remove the roles from those Users and assign them again,its showing around 1700-1800 Work Items again.(in the Work List view)